# getting Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm developing my first program with php.
I searched a lot of forums and about 3 or 4 hours, but got nothing.

Here is my index.php code:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>first program</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> program loaded successfully</h1>
    <?php
        echo extension_loaded('pgsql') ? 'yes':'no';
        echo pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test user=postgres password=root");
    ?>
</body>
```

When I load this page I see this:

```
program loaded successfully

no

Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect() in D:\courses\web programing\hw2\cinema\index.php on line 9
```

I installed php-5.4.14-Win32-VC9-x86 on my windows and run my project with this comment:

```
php.exe" -S localhost:80 -t "D:\courses\web programing\hw2\cinema"
```

I have php.ini-development and php.ini-production in php folder and Uncommented extension=php_pgsql.dll, extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll in both files. I'm using postgresql 9.2

So where is my mistake?

Comment: do `phpinfo()` and check out what is the `.ini` file you should edit.

Comment: Hmm it tell me this:Configuration File (php.ini) Path  C:\Windows . but I have no php.ini in Windows folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**
It's wired but the problem was that php try to load php.ini from Windows folder and no php.ini exist there.
So I copied one of my php.ini files in Windows folder and problem solved.
It seems like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

postgreSQL should be activates in the php.ini to activate these functions.

Comment: how to activate postgreSQL in my php.ini? (and I don't have any php.ini as i said)